# Calculate the mean values if the numbers are same

Tags: matlab, average, mean

I want to calculate the mean value if the first column numbers are same. e.g:

```
M = [ 2  0.99   0.15    0.60    0.12    0.76    0.16    0.81    0.02    0.75    0.32
      2  0.17   0.38    0.34    0.02    0.74    0.67    0.75    0.92    0.23    0.81
      2  0.26   0.16    0.30    0.29    0.74    0.89    0.12    0.65    0.06    0.79
      3  0.40   0.76    0.45    0.32    0.11    0.52    0.53    0.93    0.77    0.85
      3  0.07   0.87    0.42    0.65    0.68    0.70    0.33    0.16    0.67    0.51
      3  0.68   0.35    0.36    0.96    0.46    0.15    0.55    0.92    0.72    0.64
      3  0.40   0.69    0.56    0.94    0.21    0.95    0.40    0.79    0.64    0.95
      4  0.98   0.29    0.74    0.46    0.10    0.54    0.42    0.58    0.42    0.44
      4  0.40   0.53    0.42    0.24    0.82    0.68    0.18    0.44    0.39    0.06
      4  0.62   0.83    0.43    0.76    0.18    0.04    0.26    0.26    0.82    0.87 ]

Out=[ 2  0.47   0.23    0.41    0.15    0.75    0.57    0.56    0.53    0.35    0.64
      3  0.39   0.67    0.45    0.72    0.37    0.58    0.45    0.70    0.70    0.74
      4  0.67   0.55    0.53    0.49    0.37    0.42    0.28    0.43    0.54    0.46 ]
```

Comment: The matlab help is a great place to start.

Comment: please give a link,thank you!

Comment: Type `doc` in the console.

Comment: Thank you so much! I only know mean can do this, but have no idea about this question.

Comment: G = findgroups(M(:,1));Out = [unique(M(:,1)) splitapply(@mean, M(:,2:end), G)]

Comment: Yueli: in the future, you'll have more luck getting help if you add the right tags to your question. You should (almost) always add a language tag, as that is how most people filter the questions they see. Very few people have seen this question because very few people follow the "mean" tag. Now that Sardar added the "matlab" tag, it shows up in my feed! :)

Comment: Thanks for telling me about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
G = findgroups(M(:,1 )); 
Out = [unique(M(:,1)) splitapply(@mean, M(:,2:end), G)]
```

G = findgroups(A) returns G, a vector of group numbers created from the grouping variable A. Here G = findgroups(M(:,1 )) means pick up the first column out the matrics.

Y = splitapply(func,X,G) splits X into groups specified by G and applies the function func to each group.